# Cannot understand a Haskell exercise of fp-course

Tags: haskell

I cannot understance a answer of a exercise in fp-course.
https://github.com/system-f/fp-course/blob/7a957a177ccdc9d91323c32d576351dcc1234f2f/src/Course/Monad.hs#L119

```
-- | Flattens a combined structure to a single structure.
--
-- >>> join ((1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil) :. (1 :. 2 :. Nil) :. Nil)
-- [1,2,3,1,2]
--
-- >>> join (Full Empty)
-- Empty
--
-- >>> join (Full (Full 7))
-- Full 7
--
-- >>> join (+) 7
-- 14
join ::
  Monad k =>
  k (k a)
  -> k a
join x = id =<< x
```

While `id :: a -> a` and `(=<<) :: (a -> k b) -> k a -> k b`

Why `id` can be the first param of `(=<<)` ?
Why the answer is `join x = id =<< x`?

Comment: Hint: `a ~ k b`

Comment: Thanks. While `join (Full (Full 8))` turns out `(Full 8)`, why join `(Full 8)` cannot turn out `8`? The type is `join (Full 8) :: Num (Optional a) => Optional a` is also strange. Does `a ~ kb` has some condition for compiler?

Comment: `join :: k (k a) -> k a` how are you supposed to pass it a `k a`? If the signature were different, what should `join Empty` result in?

Comment: My Fault. I mean `id =<< (Full (Full 8))` turns out `Full 8`. Why cannot `id =<< (Full 8)` turns out `8` when `a ~ k b`. Forget join.

Comment: Look at the signature. `(=<<) :: (a -> k b) -> k a -> k b`, `k b` can't be `b`

Comment: "Why can't `id =<< Full 8` turn out `8`?" Let's say `8` is an `Int` for simplicity. So in the type `(=<<) :: (a -> k b) -> k a -> k b`, we've picked `k` to be `Optional` and `a` to be `Int` just by writing `Full 8` as the second argument. Specializing, that means we are looking at `(=<<) :: (Int -> Optional b) -> Optional a -> Optional b`. Now we have a problem: `id` can't have the type `Int -> Optional b` for any `b`. So what's this `Num` stuff all about? Well, the compiler observes that `8` could have types other than `Int`; call that other type `t`. (1/?)

Comment: So now, specializing the type of `(=<<)` with `t` instead of `Int`, we would have `(=<<) :: (t -> Optional b) -> Optional t -> Optional b`. Okay, well, `id` could have the type `t -> Optional b` if we picked `t` to be `Optional b`. But now we have a different problem: if we demand that `8 :: t` and `t` is actually `Optional b`, then we must have `8 :: Optional b`. So we need a way to interpret `8` as an `Optional b` value -- that is, we need a `Num` instance. (2/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why `id` can be the first param of `(=<<)`?

Perhaps it will help to line up the types one-to-one where they must be equal. This corresponds to the *unification* that the compiler does during typechecking.

| ↓ Term | Type → |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `(=<<)` | :: | ( | *a*<sub>1</sub> | → | *k* *b* | ) | → | *k* | *a*<sub>1</sub> | → | *k* *b* |
| `id` | :: |  | *a*<sub>2</sub> | → | *a*<sub>2</sub> |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| `(=<<) id` | :: |  |  |  |  |  |  | *k* | *a*<sub>1</sub> | → | *k* *b* |
|  |  |  | ↑ |  |  |  |  | *k* | **a<sub>2</sub>** | → | *k* *b* |
|  |  |  |  |  | ↑ |  |  | *k* | **(*k* *b*)** | → | *k* *b* |

Notice that there are two different type variables named `a`. In GHCi, you can set `:set -fprint-explicit-foralls`, and then `:type id` will show `forall a. a -> a`. This shows the local scope of the parameter `a`, like how `\x -> …` defines the scope of `x`.

> Why the answer is `join x = id =<< x`?

`(=<<)` is a combination of mapping (`fmap` / `(<$>)`) and flattening (`join`), that is, `f =<< x = join (fmap f x)`. Since `join` is flattening only, we can express `join` using `(=<<)` by setting the “mapping” part to `id`.

> `id =<< (Full (Full 8))` turns out `Full 8`. Why cannot `id =<< (Full 8)` turns out `8`

`id =<< Full (Full 8)` means we map `id` over all elements `fmap id (Full (Full 8))` = `Full (id (Full 8))` = `Full (Full 8)` and then flatten `Optional (Optional t1)` to `Optional t1`, for some type `t1`, where `8 :: (Num t1) => t1`.

If we try `id =<< Full 8` then we can map `fmap id (Full 8)` = `Full (id 8)` = `Full 8`, but we have only `Optional t1`. This is not an error, but it adds a constraint: `t1` must be equal to `Optional t2`, for some type `t2`. The syntax for that equality constraint is `t1 ~ Optional t2`. But there is no type that will work, unless you add an instance for `Num (Optional t2)`. (This is technically possible, but not standard.)